# How to get response body in scrapy downloader middleware

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I need to be able to retry the request if certain xpaths were not found on the page. So I wrote this middleware:

```
class ManualRetryMiddleware(RetryMiddleware):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if not spider.retry_if_not_found:
            return response
        if not hasattr(response, 'text') and response.status != 200:
            return super(ManualRetryMiddleware, self).process_response(request, response, spider)
        found = False
        for xpath in spider.retry_if_not_found:
            if response.xpath(xpath).extract():
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            return self._retry(request, "Didn't find anything useful", spider)
        return response
```

And registered it in `settings.py`:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.ManualRetryMiddleware': 650,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
}
```

When I run the spider, I get

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

I tried to manually create selector and run xpath on it... But the response has no `text` property and `response.body` is bytes, not str...

So how can I check page content in middleware? It's possible that some pages won't contain details that I need, so I'd like to be able to try them again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `response` doesn't contain `xpath` method is that `response` parameter in `process_response` method of downloader middleware is of type [`scrapy.http.Response`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response), see the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response). Only [`scrapy.http.TextResponse`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse) (and [`scrapy.http.HtmlResponse`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.HtmlResponse)) do have `xpath` method. So before using `xpath`, create `HtmlResponse` object from `response`. The corresponding part of your class would become:

```
...
new_response = scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(response.url, body=response.body)
if new_response.xpath(xpath).extract():
    found = True
    break
...
```

Comment: There's some gibberish in `new_response.text` now though, `specifyingscrapy.http.HtmlResponse(response.url, body=response.body, encoding="utf-8")` doesn't help.

Comment: Check @mouch 's answer. Make sure you're not working with compressed responses!

Answer (score 1):

Also take care of your middleware position. It needs to be before the  `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware` otherwise, you may end up trying to decode compressed data (which is indeed not working). Check the response.header to know if the response is compressed - `Content-Encoding: gzip`.